# What's the disadvantage of not using 404 pages?

Tags: html, http, web

Assuming a user tries to access a URL that I have not defined, the webmaster has two choices:

1. Respond with `404 Not Found` with HTML code to maintain the look-and-feel of the website and telling the user *"we cannot find this page, did you make a typo?"*
2. Respond with `200 OK` with HTML code to maintain the look-and-feel of the website and telling the user *"we cannot find this page, did you make a typo?"*

Basically, everyone seems to go with option 1, but I was thinking, why not use option 2?

What **real disadvantages** would **the webmaster** be facing if he responds to undefined URLs using `200 OK` instead of `404 Not Found`?

Comment: You can't put pages for URLs that don't exist and hence you can't return a 200 OK!

Comment: @RutwickGangurde, we definitely can. For example, on Apache we have http rewriting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're asking for real quantifiable disadvantages to using 200 rather than 404 for a 'not found' page.

The biggest ones goes back to the search engines.

Search engines will treat a 200 response as a valid page. This means that you are likely to end up with a load of pages in your search engine results that aren't useful. This is likely to damage your site's reputation with visitors who find the invalid pages.

You'll also have the disadvantage that the search engines will keep coming back to those URLs to scan them even though they're not valid, because you haven't done anything to tell them they're invalid. This won't affect you directly unless you're paying for bandwidth that your site uses. But if you are, then if the search engines are hitting invalid pages, it will increase your bandwidth costs, without any actual benefit to you. Paying for nothing is definitely a disadvantage.

Finally -- and probably more importantly -- all those 'not found' pages will be seen as duplicate content by the search engines. Search engines actively penalise sites that have multiple pages with the same content, which means that by serving a 200 code for your generic 'not found' page, you stand a very real chance of reducing your whole site's search engine rank. That's about the worst thing a site can have happen, so if you're looking for real disadvantages of using the 200 code over the 404, that's gotta be it.

Answer (score 4):

Why not go with option 2?

Because it **breaks the web**. Any automated agent will understand the missing resource to exist. Search engines will keep pointing to pages/images/resources that are no longer there.

The HTTP protocol has specific semantics - returning a 404 for a "file not found" is one of these semantics.

---

By analogy - if you send a letter to a friend. Would you rather get it back with a "no longer lives here" (404), or with... nothing to indicate something wrong (200)?

Comment: And how does it breaks the web, and what **real disadvantages** would I (the webmaster) be facing?

Comment: @Pacerier - search engine will keep indexing all missing files.

Comment: and why is *that* bad for me (the webmaster)? What's the real practical disadvantage I would face?

Comment: @Pacerier - They will keep fetching these. Your bills will be higher than they would otherwise be.

Comment: You're also unlikely to want results appearing in Google that point to your 404 page, as no user would usually want to hit your 404 page voluntarily.

Comment: @ChrisC, ...on the other hand, hitting a 404 is better than not hitting any page at all.

Comment: @Pacerier - But on a 404 you can still get a meaningful representation (as your option 1). Just saying - "no, it's all OK" is misusing the semantics. Say someone has a browser that treats 404s different that 200s? You just broke it.

Comment: @Oded, no I was saying a 404 being indexed by search engines is **better than nothing** being indexed at all. Since the 404 error page would still contain links to the website.

Comment: @Pacerier - that's a bit of a straw man. The request will contain the website address already.

Comment: @Pacerier That is true, but it's a link to a dead page: Personally I feel that if I was a user of that website, directing me to a dead-end would not cause me to look upon that website favourably.

Comment: @Oded, you are missing the point.. the request would not even happen unless the user is lead there by the search engine!

Comment: @Pacerier - Or a broken link on your site.

Comment: @Oded, your analogy is wrong. To the human user option 2 has something indicating something went wrong. To the bot, there may actually be benefits in it thinking it's actually a valid page..... (since I get more indexing compared to *no* indexing)

Comment: @Pacerier - 404s can happen for a number of reasons: You may have a typo on your site; or you may have deleted a page; or some other site may have linked to an invalid page; or someone may mistype a URL by accident (or even deliberately to see what happens). Many of those cases can lead to the search engines scanning the invalid page. If it returns a code 200, the search engine will think it's a valid page. This is bad. Especially because search engines penalise sites with duplicated pages; multiple error pages with code 200 will look like dup pages to a search engine.

Comment: @Pacerier You get more indexing, but it's inaccurate indexing.  I guess it's up to you whether you think Google links pointing to dead-ends on your site is a good thing or not: Personally I would never want this.  Also, it doesn't affect you _directly_, but as in Kant's Categorical Imperative, the wider issue is "what if everyone did this?" The web would be entirely unsearchable.

Comment: @Pacerier - see my answer for more detail as to why its bad for the search engine to start indexing every invalid URL on your site. It will harm your site in the long run.

Answer (score 2):

The 404 code is not for human visitors, but for search engines and such.

A search engine can have a tough time to determine if a response is reasonable for the request by just looking at the text in the page. The 404 code sends a clear signal that the URL doesn't lead to a useful resource. That way the search engine can list your actual pages in a search result rather than old addresses that used to lead to something.

Answer (score 1):

If something other than a human being accesses your page then you get the impression that the page exists.

This is important because without this code search engines (and other non-human users) will think the link is valid and that they have reached an actual part of your site. In real terms this would mean that someone could in principle come across the erroneous page in a search engine, because the search engine would take it as a valid part of your site.

Comment: and what **real disadvantages** would the webmaster be facing when that happens?

Comment: Do you want a search engine to take somebody to a page that doesn't exist? Does that constitute a good user experience? Do you want to pay a web hosting company to serve files to people that don't exist? If yes, then none.